How to overcome a SympifyError when substituting symbols?
I'm trying to substitute symbols from sympy and get a float as result of an equation system.
The main goal is to enter different forces (f1, f1, ...) and their angle to the x-axis and calculate the resulting force. Therefore I need a Equation System and then solve it. Because it is for school I need know the formulas and not just the result.
I tried to isolate the problem, but it seems to work just fine isolated.
from sympy import *

f1, f2, f3 = symbols('f1 f2 f3')

# Result of other calcuations
x_dir = sqrt(2)*f1/2 - f2 + sqrt(3)*f3/2


x_dir = x_dir.subs([(f1, 5), (f2, 3), (f3, 4)])
print(x_dir)

When in bigger context the same code causes an SympifyError.
from sympy import *
from math import radians

# ===== Berechnungen im 2D-Raum ======

# == Definiere alle Kräfte ==
# Name der Kraft (Variable), Winkel von ---> x-Achse in positive Richtung (nach oben positiv, nach unten negativ)

Rx = Symbol('Rx')
Ry = Symbol('Ry')

# fg = [symbols('fg'), -90]
f1 = [Symbol('f1'), 45]
f2 = [Symbol('f2'), 180]
f3 = [Symbol('f3'), -30]

all_forces = [f1, f2, f3]


def forces_to_equations(all_forces):
    x_dir = []
    y_dir = []
    for force in all_forces:
        vec_force = kraft_winkel_zu_vektor(force[0], force[1])
        x_dir.append(vec_force[0])
        y_dir.append(vec_force[1])
    
    x_dir = sum(x_dir)
    y_dir = sum(y_dir)

    return x_dir, y_dir
        

def deg_to_rad(alpha):
    alpha = alpha%360
    deg = [30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 135, 150, 180, 210, 225, 240, 270, 300, 315, 330, 360]
    rad = [pi/6, pi/4, pi/3, pi/2, 2*pi/3, 3*pi/4, 5*pi/6, pi, 7*pi/6, 5*pi/4, 4*pi/5, 3*pi/2, 5*pi/3, 7*pi/4, 11*pi/6, 2*pi]
    if alpha in deg:
        angle = rad[deg.index(alpha)]
    
    else:
        angle = radians(alpha)
    return angle


def kraft_winkel_zu_vektor(force, alpha):
    vec = [force*cos(deg_to_rad(alpha)), force*sin(deg_to_rad(alpha))]
    return vec


x_dir, y_dir = forces_to_equations(all_forces)

print(solve([x_dir-Rx, y_dir-Ry], [Rx, Ry]))


# ===== This is causing an SympifyError ======
x_dir = x_dir.subs([(f1, 5), (f2, 3), (f3, 4)])


print(solve([x_dir-Rx, y_dir-Ry], [Rx, Ry]))

Any ideas how to solve the issue?
EDIT: found solution, just forgot, that f1,... are lists and not just symbols.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Please credit answers that solved your problem. Do not simply edit your post with "found solution".

In your "bigger" context, you never defined f1, f2 and f3 as symbols (as you did in your first example). They are instead lists with a symbol and a number.
A quick fix is to simply do this before the line where you need it:
f1, f2, f3 = symbols('f1 f2 f3')
x_dir = x_dir.subs([(f1, 5), (f2, 3), (f3, 4)])

print(solve([x_dir-Rx, y_dir-Ry], [Rx, Ry]))

and you get the desired output. You cannot do this at the beginning of your code, as your code expects f1, f2 and f3 to be this list of symbols and numbers. Or you can do this at the beginning and simply change your definition of all_forces.
Another tip: Try to avoid using import *. It can make it unclear where certain functions come from. Rather import only the functions you actually need. In your case:
from sympy import symbols, Symbol, cos, sin, pi, solve

